# Extracting Specific Text From column in dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column, which I need to extract the  word with **[ft,mi,FT,MI]** of the state column using regular expression and stored in other column.

```
 df1 = {
    'State':['Arizona 4.47ft','Georgia 1023mi','Newyork 2022 NY 74.6 FT','Indiana 747MI(In)','Florida 453mi FL']}
```

**Expected output**

```
               State  Distance
0     Arizona 4.47ft  4.47ft
1     Georgia 1023mi  1023mi
2  Newyork NY 74.6ft  74.6ft
3  Indiana 747MI(In)   747MI
4   Florida 453mi FL   453mi
```

Would anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a regex pattern with the help of list `l` then use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the occurrence of this pattern from the `State` column

```
l = ['ft','mi','FT','MI']
df1['Distance'] = df1['State'].str.extract(r'(\S+(?:%s))\b' % '|'.join(l))
```

---

```
                    State Distance
0          Arizona 4.47ft   4.47ft
1          Georgia 1023mi   1023mi
2  Newyork 2022 NY 74.6FT   74.6FT
3       Indiana 747MI(In)    747MI
4        Florida 453mi FL    453mi
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i have some spaces after `74.6 FT`

Comment: Check with: `df1['State'].str.extract(r'(\S+\s?(?:%s))\b' % '|'.join(l))`